# How do I make this key detector code work?

Tags: javascript, keypress, keydown

I am making a "hotkey" for my site but the code I am using is not working.

How it is intended to work is when the user presses **CTRL** and **`** it should display an alert with the message hi. But instead it does nothing and I don't get any console error either.

Here's what I have:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
function logKey(e) {
    if (`${e.code}` == "ControlLeft" && `${e.code}` == "Backquote") {
        alert('hi');
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey instead

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ keyCode, ctrlKey }) => {
    if (ctrlKey && keyCode === 192) {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that [`keyCode` is **deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), which means you should generally avoid it. Otherwise a nicely concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) object primarily describes *one* event, along with some metadata.

## Solutions

### Simple solution

An event is fired for *each key press,* so –generally speaking– you would manually keep track of the buttons' states if you want to detect a combo.

You could do this via a dictionary:

```js
// Keep track of key states
const keys = {};
document.addEventListener("keydown", ({ code }) => keys[code] = true);
document.addEventListener("keyup", ({ code }) => keys[code] = false);

// Check for combinations on each keydown event
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  const isCtrl = keys.Control || keys.ControlLeft || keys.ControlRight;
  if (isCtrl && keys.Backquote) {
    console.log("Ctrl + Backquote combo detected.");
  }
});
```

**Important:** [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) returns a layout-agnostic identifier.

### For modifier keys

Modifier keys (e.g. *control,* shift, alt, meta) may give other keys special meaning, so the event object also includes their states. This means if you want to detect a combo with one of two keys being a modifier key, you can do a simple check like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.code === "Backquote") {
    console.log("Ctrl + Backquote combo detected.");
  }
});
```

### Layout-dependent solution

As mentioned before, `KeyboardEvent.code` returns a keyboard-independent identifier. If you want to support different layouts, you may want to use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

When one of your combo keys is a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) (e.g. `` ` `` (grave accent or backquote)), then `KeyboardEvent.key` will be `"Dead"`. [Quoting MDN (see row for key-value `"Dead"`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values#ime_and_composition_keys):

> If you wish to identify
> which specific dead key was pressed (in cases where more than one exists),
> you can do so by examining the `KeyboardEvent`'s
> associated [`compositionupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/compositionupdate_event) event's [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent/data) property.

## Note

The **deprecated** `keyCode` property's values are [not specified](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-keyboardevent-keycode). Therefore it may return a different value depending on the browser and system.

Prefer to use e.g. the `code` or `key` properties.